# How to add methods when working with RPC?

Tags: javascript, rpc

I am working with remote procedure calls and I am using a library called node-jet for that. I can add methods and can get run them remotely, but I want to ask if I can add methods remotely also ? I asked this question to library developers but can not get an answer, maybe someone here help me for that.

fn is my functions and peer is my peer

```
   var method = new jet.Method(`${this.basePath}` + '/methods/' + method)
  .on('call', fn) //function (args) {})
  peer.add(method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I've understood it,

you're looking for **bi-directional** RPC, and are currently trying to achieve it using node-jet, which may or may not provide it. Which means you may have to hand roll your own solution on top of node-jet as a transport.

Instead, you could try [Octopus](https://github.com/DhavalW/octopus), as your RPC layer... either standalone, or on top of node-jet.

I built it to solve a similar use case, over socket.io & node child processes. Hopefully it'll help you too !

To use with node-jet, you'll need to build a small custom adapter to integrate node-jet's push protocal. See the *stockTransports.js* file in the repo for examples on how socket.io, websockets etc are mapped.

just need two mappings :

```js
return {
  onRecv: // recieve function wrapper
  send:   // send function wrapper
}
```